# Exercise on recursion in C

Tags: c, string, recursion

How would you solve the following problem involving recursion?

*Implement a function with prototype* `char *repeat(char *s, int n)` *so that it creates and returns a string which consists of* n *repetitions of the input string s. For example: if the input is "Hello" and 3, the output is "HelloHelloHello". Use only recursive constructs.*

My is solution seems to me quite ugly and I am looking for something cleaner. Here is my code:

```
char *repeat(char *s, int n) {
  if(n==0) {
     char *ris = malloc(1);
     ris[0] = '\0';
     return ris;
  }
  int a = strlen(s);
  char *ris = malloc(n*a+1);
  char *ris_pre = repeat(s,n-1);
  strcpy(ris,ris_pre);
  strcpy(ris+(n-1)*a,s);
  free(ris_pre);
  return ris;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A much more tidy and elegant solution (which I've called **Basic Solution**) is as follows:

**Basic Solution**

```
char *internalRepeat(char *s, int n, size_t total)
{
    return (n > 0)
        ? strcat(internalRepeat(s, n - 1, total + strlen(s)), s)
        : strcpy(malloc(total + 1), "");
}

char *repeat(char *s, int n)
{
    return internalRepeat(s, n, 0);
}
```

This is the beauty of recursion. The key to this solution uses recursion to incrementally build the length of the result. Parameter `total` does this (not including the NUL-terminator). When the recursion terminates, the result buffer is allocated once (including the NUL-terminator) and then we use the recursion unwinding to append each copy of `s`to the result. Basic Solution behaves as follows:

1. Returns a zero-length string for any number of repetitions of an
   empty string.
2. Returns a zero-length string for zero or negative iterations of a non-empty
   string.
3. Returns a non-zero-length string for a non-zero-positive number of
   repetitions on a non-empty string.

If you create a program based on the above functions, the following statements:

```
printf("Repeat \"\" 0 times: [%s]\n", repeat("", 0));
printf("Repeat \"\" 3 times: [%s]\n", repeat("", 3));
printf("Repeat \"abcde\" 0 times: [%s]\n", repeat("abcde", 0));
printf("Repeat \"abcde\" 1 times: [%s]\n", repeat("abcde", 1));
printf("Repeat \"abcde\" 4 times: [%s]\n", repeat("abcde", 4));
```

will produce the following output:

```
Repeat "" 0 times: []
Repeat "" 3 times: []
Repeat "abcde" 0 times: []
Repeat "abcde" 1 times: [abcde]
Repeat "abcde" 4 times: [abcdeabcdeabcdeabcde]
```

**EDIT : Optimised Solution follows. Read on if you're interested in optimisation techniques.**

---

All the other proposals here principally run in **O(*n^2*)** and allocate memory at every iteration. Even though Basic Solution is elegant, uses only a single `malloc()`, and takes only two statements, surprisingly **Basic Solution also has a running time of O(*n^2*)**. This makes it very inefficient if string `s` is long and means that Basic Solution is no more efficient than any other proposal here.

**Optimised Solution**

The following is an *optimal* solution to this problem that actually runs in **O(*n*)**:

```
char *internalRepeat(char *s, int n, size_t total, size_t len)
{
    return (n > 0)
        ? strcpy(internalRepeat(s, n - 1, total, len), s) + len
        : strcpy(malloc(total + 1), "");
}

char *repeat(char *s, int n)
{
    int len = strlen(s);

    return internalRepeat(s, n, n * len, len) - (n * len);
}
```

As you can see, it now has three statements and uses one more parameter, `len`, to cache the length of `s`. It recursively uses `len` to compute the position within the result buffer where the `n`'th copy of `s` will be positioned, so allowing us to replace `strcat()` with `strcpy()` for each time `s` is added to the result. This gives an **actual running time** of O(*n*), not O(*n^2*).

**What's the difference between the Basic and Optimised solutions?**

All other solutions have used `strcat()` at least `n` times on string `s` to append `n` copies of `s` to the result. This is where the problem lies, because the implementation of `strcat()` hides an inefficiency. Internally, `strcat()` can be thought of as:

```
strcat = strlen + strcpy
```

i.e., when appending, you first have to find the end of the string you're appending to *before* you can do the append itself. This hidden overhead means that, in fact, creating `n` copies of a string requires `n` length checks and `n` physical copying operations. However, the real problem lies in that for each copy of `s` we append, our result gets longer. This means that each successive length check within `strcat()` on the *result* is also getting longer. If we now compare the two solutions using "*number of times we have to scan or copy `s`*" as our basis for comparison, we can see where the difference in the two solutions lies.

For `n` copies of the string `s`, the Basic Solution performs as follows:

```
strlen's/iteration: 2
strcpy's/iteration: 1

Iteration | Init | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... | n |   Total    |
----------+------+---+---+---+---+-----+---+------------+
Scan "s"  |   0  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... | n | (n+1)(n/2) |
Copy "s"  |   0  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |     n      |
```

whereas the Optimised Solution performs like this:

```
strlen's/iteration: 0
strcpy's/iteration: 1

Iteration | Init | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... | n |    Total   |
----------+------+---+---+---+---+-----+---+------------+
Scan "s"  |   1  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |      1     |
Copy "s"  |   0  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |      n     |
```

As you can see from the table, the Basic Solution performs (*n^2 + n)/2* scans of our string due to the built-in length check in `strcat()`, whereas the Optimised Solution always does *(n + 1)* scans. This is why the Basic Solution (and every other solution that relies on `strcat()`) performs in *O(n^2)*, whereas the Optimised Solution performs in *O(n)*.

**How does O(*n*) compare to O(*n^2*) in real terms?**

Running times make a **huge** difference when large strings are being used. As an example, let's take a string `s` of 1MB that we wish to create 1,000 copies of (== 1GB). If we have a 1GHz CPU that can scan or copy 1 byte/clock cycle, then 1,000 copies of `s` will be generated as follows:
*Note: **n** is taken from performance tables above, and represents a single scan of **s**.*

```
Basic:  (n + 1) * (n / 2) + n = (n ^ 2) / 2 + (3n / 2)
                              = (10^3 ^ 2) / 2 + (3 * 10^3) / 2
                              = (5 * 10^5) + (1.5 * 10^2)
                              = ~(5 * 10^5) (scans of "s")
                              = ~(5 * 10^5 * 10^6) (bytes scanned/copied)
                              = ~500 seconds (@1GHz, 8 mins 20 secs).

Optimised: (n + 1)            = 10^3 + 1
                              = ~10^3 (scans of "s")
                              = ~10^3 * 10^6 (bytes scanned/copied)
                              = 1 second (@1Ghz)
```

As you can see, the Optimised Solution, which completes nearly instantly, demolishes the Basic Solution which takes nearly 10 minutes to complete. However, if you think making string `s` smaller will help, this next result will horrify you. Again, on a 1GHz machine that processes 1 byte/clock cycle, we take `s` as 1KB (1 thousand times smaller), and make 1,000,000 copies (total == 1GB, same as before). This gives:

```
Basic:  (n + 1) * (n / 2) + n = (n ^ 2) / 2 + (3n / 2)
                              = (10^6 ^ 2) / 2 + (3 * 10^6) / 2
                              = (5 * 10^11) + (1.5 * 10^5)
                              = ~(5 * 10^11) (scans of "s")
                              = ~(5 * 10^11 * 10^3) (bytes scanned/copied)
                              = ~50,000 seconds (@1GHz, 833 mins)
                              = 13hrs, 53mins, 20 secs

Optimised: (n + 1)            = 10^6 + 1
                              = ~10^6 (scans of "s")
                              = ~10^6 * 10^3 (bytes scanned/copied)
                              = 1 second (@1Ghz)
```

This is a truly shocking difference. Optimised Solution performs in the same time as before as the total amount of data written is the same. However, Basic Solution stalls for over **half a day** building the result. This is the difference in running times between O(*n*) and O(*n^2*).

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach where you allocate the string only once :

```
char *repeat(char *s, int n) {
   int srcLength = strlen(s);
   int destLength = srcLength * n + 1;      
   char *result = malloc(destLength);
   result[0] = '\0'; // This is for strcat calls to work properly

   return repeatInternal(s, result, n);
}

char *repeatInternal(char *s, char *result, int n) {
  if(n==0) {
     return result;
  }

  strcat(s, result);  
  return repeat(result, s, n-1);
}
```

The second repeat method should be used only by the first one. (the first one is your prototype method)

Note : I did not compile/test it but this should work.

Comment: Doesn't it say "n *repetitions of the input string* s"? Hence 0 repetitions would be the empty string.

Comment: You should allocate `srcLength * n + 1` bytes. Your current calculation won't have room for the null terminator.

Comment: @interjay ur right this will also solve the annoying if at the beginning

Comment: C doesn't have function overloading, you should rename the second function. By the way, you can remove the `if` in the first function to simplify a bit.

Comment: Thanks updated as well. (been a long time since I coded in c :))

Comment: Good call for allocating the string in one go, however your solution still runs in O(n^2)! Plus you should confirm if it compiles. Please see my optimised solution for a true O(n) solution.

Comment: Well, the OP didn't ask for optimized he just asked for a cleaner solution :)

Answer (score 2):

This is one:

```
char *repeat (char *str, int n)
{
  char *ret_str, *new_str;

  if (n == 0)
  {
    ret_str = strdup ("");
    return ret_str;
  }
  ret_str = repeat (str, n-1);
  new_str = malloc (sizeof (char) * strlen (str) * (n + 1));
  new_str[0] = '\0';
  strcpy (new_str, ret_str);
  strcat (new_str, str);
  free (ret_str);
  return new_str;
}
```

We can get someone neater looking code with `realloc ()`

```
char *repeat (char *str, int n)
{
  char *ret_str;

  if (n == 0)
  {
    ret_str = strdup ("");
    return ret_str;
  }
  ret_str = repeat (str, n-1);
  ret_str = realloc (ret_str, sizeof (char) * strlen (str) * (n + 1));
  strcat (ret_str, str);
  return ret_str;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Ok, **this one is more compact**.

```
char *repeat (char *str, int n)
{
  static char *ret_str;
  static int n_top = -1;

  if (n >= n_top)
    ret_str = calloc (sizeof (char), strlen (str) * n + 1);
  if (n <= 0)
    return ret_str;

  n_top = n;

  return strcat (repeat (str, n-1), str);
}
```

We use a static buffer to hold the final string, therefore one single buffer is used throughout in all the levels of recursion.

The `static int n_top` holds the value of the previous value of `n` from recursive calls. This is initialized by `-1` to handle the case when called with `n = 0`, and thus it returns an empty string (and for which `calloc` is used to initialize with 0). At the first recursive call the value is `-1` therefore only at the top level `n > n_top` is true (as `n` is always decreasing), and in this case the entire buffer is allocated `ret_str`. Else we find for the bottom condition, which is when `n` becomes 0. At this point when `n = 0` we return the address of the pre-allocated static buffer `ret_str` to the parent callers in the recursion tree. This single buffer is then used by each level of recursion appended by `str` and handed over to the previous level, until it reaches the `main`.

**EDIT 2**

**Even more compact one, but ugly**

```
char *repeat (char *str, int n)
{
  static int n_top;
  n_top = (n_top == 0)? n: n_top;
  return (n <= 0)?(n=n_top,n_top=0,calloc (sizeof (char), strlen (str) * n + 1)):strcat (repeat (str, n-1), str);
}
```

The last compact code had a problem if you would use call with `repeat (str, n); repeat (str, 0);`. This implementation overcomes that problem and also it is even more compact one also using only one function.

Note that there is an ugly `(n=n_top,n_top=0,calloc (sizeof (char), strlen (str) * n + 1))`. Here we ensure while rolling back up we use the value of `n_top` to allocate memory and then reset `n_top` to `0` so that the function has `n_top` set to `0` in the next call from `main ()` or other main caller (not recursive). This can be done in more readable way, but this looks cool. I would recommend to stick with a more readable one.

**EDIT 3**

**The mad-man version**

This overcomes repetitive `strlen ()` calls. `strlen ()` is called only once, and then the value of the string length along with the value of `n` in the current depth is used to find the `offset` value which indicates the end of the final string being returned (whose address is not stored in any intermediate variable, just returned and passed). When passing the string to `memcpy` we add the offset and give the source memory location to `memcpy` by adding `offset` to the returned answer string from the immediately next depth. This actually provides `memcpy` the location immediately after the string end, after which `memcpy` copies the stuff `str` of length `str_len`. Note that `memcpy` will return the destination address which it was passed, that is the answer string end address of this depth, but we need the actual beginning, which is achieved by going back `offset` from this returned value, and that is why `offset` is subtracted before returning.

Note this *still* uses single function :D

```
char *repeat (char *str, int n)
{
  static int n_top, str_len;
  int offset = 0;

  (n_top == 0)?(n_top = n,str_len = strlen (str)):(offset = str_len * (n_top-n));
  return (n <= 0)?(n=n_top,n_top=0,malloc (str_len * n + 1)):(memcpy (repeat (str, n-1) + offset, str, str_len) - offset);
}
```

Some notes:

- We may have done `offset = str_len * (n-1)` in which case in the first depth the `str` would be copied in offset 0, from subsequent recursive depths it would copy the string to the answer string from reverse.
- When doing `memcpy` we tell it to copy `n` bytes, which does not include `\0` . But as we use `calloc` to allocate the final destination memory with the space for the terminating `'\0' character, it is initialized to 0. Therefore the final string will be '\0' terminated.
- sizeof (char) is always 1
- To make it look more compact and cryptic remove `offset` calculation and directly calculate the offset in the last `return` expression.
- DO NOT use this code in real life.

Comment: The version with the static buffer works only once: you cannot do e.g. `repeat("Hello")` and then `repeat("Cruel World")` - it will crash!

Comment: @anatolyg: <strike>Very good point.</strike>. Why, see the `if (n > n_top)` condition. Everytime it is at the top level it will allocate new buffer.

Comment: @anatolyg: it doesnot crash. and the buffer is not allocated once. For each top level call one buffer is allocated.

Comment: A suggestion for the compact version: initialize `ret_str` to NULL and in the `if (n > n_top)` case free it if not NULL before allocating space again, or realloc and memset to 0's.

Comment: @slashmais: Good suggestion, but i have avoided it to make it modular, because the responsibility to free the string is of the caller, as other string library functions. If the caller doesn't free, then we would have a leak. The function should not be bothered about if it was called before or would be called after.

Comment: Yes, although I feel a more "correct" `repeat()`-function prototype for the OP should have included a third parameter as a string sized by the caller to sufficient size ('`strlen(s) * n +1`).

Comment: The function signature is is provided by the asker, therefore i have used that constraint. But we can derive the length of the string at any level of recursion, and therefore no need to pass a length parameter. Also telling to concatenate "hello" `n` times and also giving the target string length is redundant, as the final string length can be derived.

Comment: Using _n_ to track the length of the result on your internal function was good and the key to the solution. However, reliance on static variables in this case was bad style, and unnecessary as it happens. See my answer for a much more elegant (and even more compact) implementation of your solution.

Comment: @aps2012: Yes it is a good one. I just wanted to avoid an auxiliary function.

Comment: @phoxis Indeed, I did notice you were the only one to do it using a single function. That deserves recognition.

Comment: @aps2012: I think you would like the new update, even more compact.

Comment: @phoxis Ah, the comma separator is always a good friend when compacting code! Nice try! You still use `strcat()`, though, which means that your running time is O(_n^2_)! I used to use `strcat()` but I have a new optimised version which doesn't, so now I run in O(_n_).

Comment: @aps2012: bingo! removed repetitive string length calculation, still single function. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that requires a bit more code, but it runs in O(log n) time instead of O(n):

```
// Return a string containing 'n' copies of 's'
char *repeat(int n, char *s) {
  return concat((n-1) * strlen(s), strdup(s));
}

// Append 'charsToAdd' characters from 's' to 's', charsToAdd >= 0
char *concat(int charsToAdd, char *s) {
  int oldLen = strlen(s);
  if (charsToAdd <= n) {  // Copy only part of the original string.
    char *longerString = malloc((oldLen + charsToAdd + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(longerString, s);
    strncat(longerString, s, charsToAdd);
    return longerString;
  } else { // Duplicate s and recurse.
    char *longerString = malloc((2 * oldLen + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(longerString, s);
    strcat(longerString, s);
    free(s);  // Free the old string; the recusion will allocate a new one.
    return concat(charsToAdd - oldLen, longerString);
  }
}
```

Comment: It requires `O(log n)` *additional space on the stack*, not time

Comment: @anatolyg - Not sure what you mean.  Each call to `concat()` doubles the length of the string, so for example, a repeat count of 64 requires only 6 calls, whereas all of the other solutions require either 63 or 64.  So this solution saves both time and stack space.

Comment: @AdamLiss Actually, your algorithm runs in O(_n_). Your execution time requires O(_log n_) recursions, agreed, but _n_ in this case refers to the length of the result (i.e. the number of bytes in the result). Your implementation still allocates memory for (_n_ * `strlen(s)`) bytes and copies (_n_ * `strlen(s)`) bytes to complete. It doesn't create a result of (_n_ * `strlen(s)`) bytes by copying and allocating only (_log(n)_ * `strlen(s)`) bytes, therefore it cannot be called O(_log n_) running time.

Comment: @aps2012 Thanks for the clarification.  I guess the running time depends on where the program spends most of its time: in `strcat()` and `strcpy()` (in which case the execution time will be O(n)), or in `malloc()`, and how the execution time of `malloc()` relates to the number of bytes that are being allocated.  I'm inclined to think it will spend the bulk of its time copying data, which would indeed make it execute in O(n).

Comment: @AdamLiss You're right in your analysis in that it spends most of its time in `strcat()` and `strlen()`. However, I realised that this actually makes a running time of O(_n^2_), not O(_n_). The reason is that `strcat()` is performed on the _result_ (which is growing every iteration), not the original string. I used to use `strcat()` but now I've optimised it away to get a true O(_n_). Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char *repeat(char *s, int n)
{
    static char *sret=NULL;
    static int isnew=1;

    if (!s || !s[0])
    {
        if (sret) { free(sret); sret=NULL; }
        return "";
    }

    if (n<=0) return "";

    if (isnew)
    {
        int nbuf = strlen(s)*n + 1;
        sret = (char*)realloc(sret, nbuf);
        memset(sret, 0, nbuf);
        isnew=0;
    }

    strcat(sret,s);
    repeat(s, n-1);
    isnew = 1;
    return sret;
}

int main()
{
    char *s = repeat("Hello",50);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    s = repeat("Bye",50);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    repeat(NULL,0); /* this free's the static buffer in repeat() */

    s = repeat("so long and farewell",50);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

[edit]
A variation of aps2012's solution that uses a single function, but with a static int:

```
char *repeat(char *s, int n)
{
    static int t=0;
    return (n > 0) 
        ? (t += strlen(s),strcat(repeat(s, n - 1), s)) 
        : strcpy(malloc(t + 1), "");
}
```

The caller has to `free()` the returned string to avoid memory leaks.